# Reorder legend, colours and stacked plot in R with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-bar-chart

I have a dataset (df) with the following structure. The complete dataset has 6 years of data.

| histo_period | City | percent | participants |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jul 20 - Aug 20 | London | 50 | 100 |
| Jul 20 - Aug 20 | New York | 20 | 40 |
| Jul 20 - Aug 20 | Paris | 30 | 60 |
| Sep 22 - Oct 22 | London | 10 | 50 |
| Sep 22 - Oct 22 | New York | 60 | 300 |
| Sep 22 - Oct 22 | Paris | 30 | 150 |
| Nov 21 - Dec 21 | London | 45 | 45 |
| Nov 21 - Dec 21 | New York | 25 | 25 |
| Nov 21 - Dec 21 | Paris | 30 | 30 |

I've been trying to create a stacked plot with ggplot in R. However, I have issues with the order of the periods as it doesn't show it chronologically, the colours should be as the 'colours_order' but R is showing other colours, and the cities should be shown in the city_order (Paris, London, New York), but R is showing the legend in alphabetic order, and the stacked plot in different order.

```
city_order <- c("Paris", "London", "New York")

colours_order <- c("#297D96", "#68C7E6", "#9BBB59")

ggplot(df, aes(x=histo_period, y=percent, fill=City)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "fill", stat="identity") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = setNames(colours_order, city_order)) +
    labs(x = "Year", y= "Percent", fill ="") + 
    theme_light() + 
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle= 0), 
          legend.position = "top", 
          axis.line = element_line(size = 0, colour = "black"),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

I need to create a stacked plot using R that look like the following one [image]

Also, I need to display the total number of participants on the top of each bar as shown in the image.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help. table youincluded is not a farom of reproducible example. better use dput() command

Answer (score 0):

You could first convert your city column to a `factor` with the `levels` order and order your data based on the city like this:

```r
city_order <- c("Paris", "London", "New_York")
colours_order <- c("#297D96", "#68C7E6", "#9BBB59")

df$City <- factor(df$City, levels = city_order)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df[order(df$City),], aes(x=histo_period, y=percent, fill=City, group = histo_period)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours_order) +
  labs(x = "Year", y= "Percent", fill ="") + 
  theme_light() + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle= 0), 
        legend.position = "top", 
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0, colour = "black"),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data used:**

```
df = read.table(text = "histo_period    City    percent participants
Jul20-Aug20 London  50  100
Jul20-Aug20 New_York    20  40
Jul20-Aug20 Paris   30  60
Sep22-Oct22 London  10  50
Sep22-Oct22 New_York    60  300
Sep22-Oct22 Paris   30  150
Nov21-Dec21 London  45  45
Nov21-Dec21 New_York    25  25
Nov21-Dec21 Paris   30  30
", header = TRUE)
```